# GPIO 2 and 3 wont go low on PI B+

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a project that is using almost all of the GPIO available on the pi B+ so I have chosen to use GPIO 2 and 3 (pins 3 & 5) to drive relays. These pins also act as `SDA` and `SCL`. Using `RPi.GPIO` I cannot get these two GPIOs to go low. Is there another package that woul work or a configuration somewhere? I have blacklisted the `I2C` drivers.

Comment: You may have to change [device tree configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/pin-configuration.md)

Comment: You could get an MCP23017 i2c GPIO expander and connect it to the two remaining GPIOs to get 16 extra pins.